Do we have any dynamic scheduler in OCI cloud where we can run jobs based on product types with different schedules
Do we have any dynamic scheduler in OCI cloud where we can run jobs based on product types with different schedules.
For Example:
X product needs to run 5 times a day with start X and End Y time.
Y product needs to run 30 times a day with start at X and End at Y time.
Need inputs if any solution exists in OCI cloud
